Analysis quality and robustness of a BLE connection
I need some help. This is my first project with Bluetooth Low-Energy. I'm mandated to create a POC to analyze the quality and the robustness of a BLE connection.
I had read the BLUETOOTH LOW ENERGY, THE DEVELOPER'S HANDBOOK by Robin Heydon to first have a nice overview of the BLE protocol but I'm kind of lost. I'm gonna explain a little bit more about what we are using and what we wanna analyze
That we are using

Our DUT (Device under test) has a nRF52840 from Nordic Semi
We don't want to use a phone as the central since we can't really configure the connection parameters

That we want to analyze (KPIs)

number of connect/disconnect without pairing/bonding in a time interval
number of connection lost in a time interval
distance to disconnect
distance to reconnect


if possible, time to reconnect


data throughput


measure real large payload
find a generic service and measure data loopback time


RSSI
Study how connection parameters influence the KPIs above

I don't really understand how I can measure this connection's quality. My first thought was to use a sniffer, as we already own an Ellisys Tracker or a nRF52840 DK. However I'm not sure if the tracker can provide every statistic we want. I don't have a really good understand of the DTM (Direct Test Mode) too. How can this mode analyze wireless connections while being wired ? Is it trustable in my case ?
I didn't find as much as recent informations about analysis BLE connection online a part to sniff and debug.
Some questions
Is it a good idea to use a sniffer in that case ? If not, what would you consider as an other option ?
What kind of device can I use as the central if the phone is prohibited ? I found that the BLE's API from Windows 10 wasn't good back in 2016. Did it change ? Btw I'm using WSL but it doesn't support BLE and I don't really want to recompile the kernel...
I believe that when the DUT is advertising mode, the Tx will be more powerful that during connection. Does it mean that the DUT will be scan able afar than during connection ? It isn't link with data throughput, right ?
I would like to thanks in advance everyone taking the time to read this post and provide an explanation or an answer.

Why don't you just use a nRF as central as well? In any case, I think it's easiest to simply log the events from the Bluetooth stack directly on the nRF devices instead of trying to sniff.

@Emil I will dig a bit further about using the nRF as central. I knew this was a possibility but I didn't really saw the advantages instead of sniff the traffic.

As Emil said, your best option would be to use another nRF52840, especially given that it is your DUT which you will have to learn to use anyway, and therefore you will not need to learn how to use a new device. If your plan is to use Zephyr/nRF Connect SDK (which is what I would recommend), then you can technically use any other supported nRF device from the list here. You can also modify one of the existing samples/demos/tests that are found here:-

Zephyr BLE sample apps
Using Zephyr shell for BLE operations
Zephyr test framework

If you prefer that the other device uses a different hardware/stack, then my recommendation is to use a BlueZ device as it will most likely be the easiest/most documented/most mature option. You can use a Raspberry Pi for this option or any Linux machine with Bluetooth support (or an attached BLE dongle).
To answer your main question, a Bluetooth sniffer will not be very suitable for this use case. Sniffers are best used for debugging specific wireless/stack issues and not for automation or stress testing. As for Direct Test Mode, it might be useful for testing some of the criteria but it is more focused on testing the physical layer and the radio (which is why it is mainly used for certification/qualification), therefore my recommendation is to not rely on it alone for your testing.
Some other useful links:-

Testing BLE peripheral using python script
Multiple BLE device testing
Developing and testing on nRF52 in Renode and Zephyr


Thanks for the explanations and the useful links, that helps me to have a more precise understanding. I will go with the nRF52840 and Zephyr.
